# How do you squeeze an image in a squared div for a zoom

Tags: html, css

I wanted to put a non-squared image into a square div. I used the `overflow: hidden` on the div in order to clip the overlap of the image. Works.

But how do I make sure the image is centered and is not positioned at 0, 0, in the top-left hand corner? Setting the these values manually is no option.

Any hints?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this easily using `absolute` and `relative` positioning. For example:

```
#myImage {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#myImage img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -25%;
    left: -50%;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bekjR/). You might need to alter the positioning of the image depending upon its size.

Comment: Nothing more needed than this! Thank you.